# Compare if two or more chars are different in two strings

Tags: c#, string, char, compare

I want to compare if two or more chars are different in two strings.
For example

```
var string1 = "test1" 
var string2 = "trsz1"
```

And now I want to check, if >= 2 chars are different in this 2 strings, it should output false.
How you will do it?

Comment: Are you trying to compare characters from those strings, one by one (first character by first character, second by second and ...)?

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. it is for help with existing programming problems. Please read [ask]

Comment: Yes this will be an option

Comment: I have an Programm code, but know i want to compare the strings to sort them to false or true

Comment: @daaemoon are your input strings the same size?

Comment: No not ever, my strings are from the length 4-5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the algorithm is called Levenshtein Distance

```
public static int ComputeLevenshteinDistance(string strA, string strB)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strA) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(strB))
    {
        return Math.Max(strA == null ? 0 : strA.Length, strB == null ? 0 : strB.Length);
    }
    int[,] iArray = new int[strA.Length + 1, strB.Length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= strA.Length; i++)
    {
        iArray[i, 0] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= strB.Length; i++)
    {
        iArray[0, i] = i;
    }
    int iCost;
    int[] iMin = new int[3];
    for (int i = 1; i <= strA.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= strB.Length; j++)
        {
            iCost = (strA[i - 1] == strB[j - 1]) ? 0 : 1;
            iMin[0] = iArray[i - 1, j] + 1;
            iMin[1] = iArray[i, j - 1] + 1;
            iMin[2] = iArray[i - 1, j - 1] + iCost;
            iArray[i, j] = iMin.Min();
        }
    }
    return iArray[strA.Length, strB.Length];
}
```

so you can do..

```
string string1 = "test1" ;
string string2 = "trsz1";

bool IsDifferent = ComputeLevenshteinDistance(string1, string2) >= 2;
```

`ComputeLevenshteinDistance` calculates the number of changes you need to make to turn string1 into string2. If you want to count a twist as one change you need the Damerau Levenshtein Distance

Comment: my fault .. change `ComputeLevenshteinDistance(string1, string2) > 2` to `ComputeLevenshteinDistance(string1, string2) >= 2`

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are always the same length it's pretty easy:

```
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < string1.Length; i++)
{
  if(string1[i] != string2[i]) count++;
}
return count < 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

> but now i want to compare the strings to sort them to false or true

If your strings are the same size you may try this:

```
var string1 = "test1";
var string2 = "trsz1";

var result = string1.Zip(string2, (f, s) => f == s ? true : false).ToList();
//result: true, false, true, false, true

var ifTwoOrMoreDifferent = result.Count(i => i == false) > 1;
```

If your inputs are not the same size then your last line may be modified as follow:

```
var lengthDif = Math.Abs(string1.Length-string2.Length);
var ifTwoOrMoreDifferent = result.Count(i => i == false) + lengthDif > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string1 = "test1" ;
var string2 = "trsz1";

string1.Zip(string2, (x, y) =>  x.Equals(y)).Where(c=>!c).Count() >= 2


Console.WriteLine(string1.Zip(string2, (x, y) =>  x.Equals(y)).Where(c=>!c).Count() >= 2);
```

You should also aware of [`zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) constraints/limitations.

> The method steps through the two input sequences, applying function
>   resultSelector to corresponding elements of the two sequences. The
>   method returns a sequence of the values that are returned by
>   resultSelector. **If the input sequences do not have the same number of
>   elements, the method combines elements until it reaches the end of one
>   of the sequences.** For example, if one sequence has three elements and
>   the other one has four, the result sequence has only three elements.

Working [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PsOpbG)